# How does dependency injection work in ATG?

Tags: atg

I am new to ATG and trying to understand the basic concepts.I read many articles about it but the concept is still not clear to me.

Comment: Have you even read the ATG help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foo.java

```
package my.foopackage;
import my.custompackageCustomClass.CustomClass;

public class Foo {

    private CustomClass customClass;

    public void setCustomClass (CustomClass customClass){
        this.customClass = customClass;
    }

    public CustomClass getCustomClass() {
        return customClass;
    }
}
```

CustomClass.java

```
package my.custompackageCustomClass;

public class CustomClass {
    private String myProperty;

    public void setMyProperty (CustomClass myProperty){
        this.myProperty = myProperty;
    }

    public CustomClass getMyProperty() {
        return myProperty;
    }
}
```

Foo.properties

```
$class=my.foopackage.Foo
$scope=global

customClass=/path/to/configuration/file/ofYourWantedCustomClass/CustomClass
```

CustomClass.properties

```
$class=my.custompackageCustomClass.CustomClass
$scope=global

myProperty=myProperty1
```

Note that you could have multiple properties files for your components.
e.g.: CustomClass1.properties, CustomClass2.properties etc and you could have different values for String myProperty.
It helps me think it like a second layer of polymorphism (on instance level) but the main difference is that all components are configurable via /dyn/admin and layered configuration.

Answer (score 3):

This is all explained in the documentation, and also in the basic Foundation course.

In ATG, you define 'components'. These are *named* instances of a given class.

You define these components by using `.properties` files. The path and name of the properties file, relative to a config root, becomes the name of your component.

The `.properties` file contains the name of the class to be instantiated

The file also defines the scope of the instance, i.e. whether, once instantiated, the object should exist only for the current request, the current session, or the duration of the application (global)

In addition, you can define any property values for your component. These can be by value (particularly for primitive data types) or by reference to another component, by name.

When you start up an instance of an ATG EAR, it is the Nucleus that is started up. The Nucleus is a bean container, and is responsible for the lifecycle of the components defined therein.

The Nucleus instantiates components when the components are first accessed. The process of instantiation is as follows (simplified greatly)

- The Nucleus will create the object instance by calling the no-argument constructor of the class.
- The component will be given the name, derived from its `.properties` file location, and held in the specified scope.
- The Nucleus will then go through all the properties defined in the `.properties` file and call the `setXXX(...)` method on the object to set the values.
- For objects by value (defined by value in the properties file), the property will be set directly.
- For objects by reference (defined by the name of a Nucleus component in the properties file), the referenced component will be looked up in the appropriate scope and if it exists, then will be set on the property. If the referenced component has not been instantiated yet, then the Nucleus will insatiate that component first (following this same procedure for that component) and then set that object will be set on the property

This last step is how ATG does dependency injection.

In short, what this means is that if your class A has a dependency on an instance of class B, then as a developer, you do not write the code to instantiate class B, or to look up and bind to an instance of class B. As long as you fulfil basic requirements[1], you write your code for class A with the implicit assumption that you will always be given a value of class B. You then configure an instance of class B as a component, an instance of class A as a component and you reference the property of class A to the instance of class B, and the Nucleus will ensure that when code in class A executes, it will already have been injected with a valid instance of class B.

[1] Class A and B must have no-argument constructors, class A must have a writeable property of type B (e.g. it must have a `public void setB(B myB)` method)

Comment: Thank you for an easy explanation.

Comment: No problem, @SanchitaDharmadhikary. I am sure I thought you this in the initial training course :)

Answer (score 1):

ATG DI model uses Nucleus for managing the object graph and each inject-able bean needs to be configured as Nucleus components.

Check http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52191_03/Platform.11-1/ATGPlatformProgGuide/html/s0201nucleusorganizingjavabeancompone01.html